# Need to read content from a subpage on sub domain using .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I want my sub domain to read contents of a specific page. This is my current .htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.citywideapp\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://citywideapp.com/subpage.php?rep=$1 [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

What I exactly want is for a sub domain murray.citywideapp.com, it should read contents of citywideapp.com/subpage.php?rep=murray

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Akif

Comment: What is happening when you access your "murray.citywideapp.com" url?

Comment: First, It changes the url in the address bar with: http://citywideapp.com/subpage.php?rep=                                    It should not change the url in the address bar, secondly no value after rep=, as there should be the city name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.citywideapp\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!subpage\.php).*)$ subpage.php?rep=%1 [L,QSA,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It is giving up an "Internal Server Error". You can check it by going on to: http://murray.citywideapp.com/

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your effort. Its working this time, the only problem is, its loading the CSS files.

Comment: For that you can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current page's URL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.citywideapp\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !^(www|ftp|mail)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://citywideapp.com/subpage.php?rep=%1 [R,L]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subpage.php?rep=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```